# Common basic information and research for journal club presentation

Tags: publications, journals

I'm currently in the process of preparing a journal club presentation (I'm a Psychogeriatrics physician). I've done a couple before, but always seem to re-invent the wheel when it comes to what basic information should be covered.

For example: checking author biographies and previous work so that I have a sense for the context, potential conflicts of interest, etc.

Other areas I usually cover: papers that cite this article, funding sources and journal impact factor.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

PaulV's contribution is excellent.  In addition:  Understand the context that the paper appeared in, i.e. try to understand why the author wrote the article.  See the article in its historical context.

Answer (score 0):

My PhD advisor would have us do journal reviews in class.  In addition to some of the things you've listed, we also were encouraged to include the following:  the formal citation format of the paper, definition of any acronyms that may be unfamiliar to others, brief summary of other related papers by the same author (for context), areas of concern or possible sources of error in the paper, and how the paper relates to your own research.

For journal club specifically, we would also bring along related articles that either had different points of view or were written from a different frame of reference.  This helped to bring perspective to the paper.